# Action after click on submit button (php)

Tags: php, wampserver

I have created a page on php language that contains list of files, stored in a folder and button submit. When I press the submit button, the files stored in the folder, sent to the file server. I want to add paragraph where I can add download link of downloaded file. I wrote the small function display() where If I clicking on submit button, shows 2 strings, "Download link:" and variable $text, where I store download link, but function doesn't work at all, it can't show the simple text after clicking on submit button and I do not know why. Help me understand what the problem may be.

Important moment, I have to use the php language only.

---

The problem is that I did not called a function.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>For test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
<?php
                function display()
                {
                    $text = 'link';
                    print "Download link: ";
                    echo $text;
                }
                if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                   display();
                }
            ?>
            <div style="border-bottom: 2px solid black; border-top: 2px solid black; background-color: white; width: 25%; text-align: center; display: block; margin: auto; ">
                <?php foreach ($files as $file) { ?>
                    <p style="text-align: inherit"><?php echo $file; ?></p>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>

            <p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
            <div style="text-align: center; float: inherit; margin-top: 5%">
                <form method="post" action="">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit"><br><br>
                </form>
            </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you missed the `<?php` opening tag. any way I think you have to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

Comment: Incorrectly copied :(

Comment: are you sure 'display()' is not called? maybe there is problem with its code

Comment: Please edit your question to rectify typing mistake.

Comment: Tamar, yes, it is. Thank you very much!

Comment: The problem is solved!

Comment: Then please give you r own answer, or delete the question,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>For test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
             <?php
                function display()
                {
                    $text = 'link';
                    print "Download link: ";
                    echo $text;
                }
                if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                   display();
                }
            ?>
            <div style="border-bottom: 2px solid black; border-top: 2px solid black; background-color: white; width: 25%; text-align: center; display: block; margin: auto; ">
                <?php foreach ($files as $file) { ?>
                    <p style="text-align: inherit"><?php echo $file; ?></p>
                <p> <?php display(); ?> </p>
            </div>

            <p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
            <div style="text-align: center; float: inherit; margin-top: 5%">
                <form method="post" action="">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit"><br><br>
                </form>
            </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script has error 
@

```
<body">

should be 

<body>
```

and you need to start php tag after that as

```
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed PHP tag syntax. every php function and code must be in PHP tag. updated code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>For test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <?php    
            function display()
            {
                $text = 'link';
                print "Download link: ";
                echo $text;
            }
            
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
               display();
            }
        ?>

        <div style="border-bottom: 2px solid black; border-top: 2px solid black; background-color: white; width: 25%; text-align: center; display: block; margin: auto; ">
            <?php foreach ($files as $file) { ?>
                <p style="text-align: inherit"><?php echo $file; ?></p>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
        <div style="text-align: center; float: inherit; margin-top: 5%">
            <form method="post" action="">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit"><br><br>
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is that I did not called a function.

Comment: explain you problem briefly. so i can help you.